# Bash; check if certain lines contain characters

Tags: bash

```
if grep -q "_" "${changefile}"; then
  fail
  printf "\nUnderscores are invalid in hostnames\n" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

I have this snippet in place as a method to check a DNS configuration file if it contains an underscore; an invalid character. If so, it will crash.

I need to rewrite this so it checks if any of the hostnames contain invalid characters. The hostnames are on lines 27-350.

My idea's logic revolves around: *"if grep -q "${changefile}" lines 27 through 350 returns any invalid characters; complain and exit"*. Just not sure how to code that.

Quoting Microsoft's website, a hostname must satisfy the fact that characters only:

> in the range of 'A-Z', 'a-z','0-9', '.' and '-' are used.

Comment: You can use `sed -n '27,350p' "$changefile"` to get lines 27 through 350 of the file.

Comment: Would this work for those characters?
    regex='^[]0-9a-zA-Z.[-]'

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '27<=NR && NR<=350 && !/A-Za-z0-9.-/{f=1; 
                                           print "invalid chars at line:" NR,$0; exit} 
                                       END{exit f}' file
```

this will exit after the first failure, alternatively you can validate all lines and report what all failed (to do that remove the `exit` in the first block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How do I pass in the ${changefile} file into that expression? Sorry if I'm a super noob, I just started Bash like a week ago

Comment: if it's the filename, replace `file` in the posted script with `"$changefile"`

Answer (score 0):

You dont give enough about your line.

You can try this sed

```
sed '
27,350!bA
/_/!d
s/.*/& --> invalid line : contain _/
q
:A
$s/.*/no problem/p
d' infile
```